# How to use "fill_factor" in spilu (scipy)

Tags: numerical-analysis, python, scipy, preconditioning

I am using spilu (incomplete LU decomposition for sparse matrix) in scipy: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html

However there is an option call "fill_factor" which is quite unclear to me.

If fill_factor=100, does it mean the matrix is full; and fill_factor=50 means the matrix is half-full?

Comment: This is a question you should ask on the scipy forums.

Comment: `scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu` is an interface to the SuperLU library & your parameter is well explained in the [SuperLU manual](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/superlu_ug.pdf). incomplete LU will generate some fill-in (i.e. the factors will have more non-zeros than the original matrix). the fill factor is the simply the _expected fill-in ratio_, which tells the algorithm how much memory to pre-allocate for the new non-zero elements. this may reduce (1) memory fragmentation and (2) the no of calls to malloc/free

Comment: @GoHokies Thank you! So how do we know a priori what value to choose for the fill_factor? Any rule of thumb, or only trial and error ?

Comment: ideally, you'd use your knowledge about the particular matrix structure, do some trial-and error experiments with smaller matrix sizes, perhaps do some [re-ordering of rows/columns to reduce fill-in](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview), etc. have a look at the SuperLU manual...